# Date parser function for hh:mm:ss.sss format

Tags: python, date-parsing

I have a time stamp with hh:mm:ss.sss format

```
2013-11-02 00:00:00.125
```

How can I parse this kind of value in python?

The 3 digits in the end may differ in another value

I mean .825 or something different

I tried with this function

```
parseA=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.SSS')
```

but it does not match

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior - that's not how you do microseconds (it's expecting a literal period and three literal capital Ss!).

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`%f` format code](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to parse the microseconds.

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2013-11-02 00:00:00.125', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 2, 0, 0, 0, 125000)
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way of parsing arbitrary dates is to use the [`dateutil.parser.parse()`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) method of [`python-dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html):

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> timestamp = "2013-11-02 00:00:00.125"
>>> parse(timestamp)
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 2, 0, 0, 0, 125000)
```